# Removing multiple JSON objects inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to create a loop that removes JSON objects from my JSON array based on whether any `<p>` elements have the selected class.

So, how I want it to work is when the form is submitted I check to see if any `<p>` elements have the selected class. If any of the elements are selected I loop through them using their text value to remove them from the JSON array, then I `console.log()` the array.

I am able to remove a single object from the array using the code inside the loop but I can't seem to get it to work with my loop. How can I achieve this?

**JS**

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if( $('.postcodes p.selected').length ){
        $('.postcodes p.selected').each(function(){
            var data_filter = area_json.filter((element) => {
                return element.Sector !== $(this).text();
            });
        });
    }

    console.log(data_filter); 
}); 

var area_json = [
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 1",
       "Locality": "Thistle Court,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 1147
    },
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 6",
       "Locality": "Great Western Road,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 4596
    },
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 7",
       "Locality": "Holburn Street,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 4380
    }
]
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="postcodes">
        <p class="selected">AB10 1</p>
        <p class="selected">AB10 6</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may retrieve selected options `.text()` by simply doing `[...$('.selected')].map(p => $(p).text())`, than you may filter out those `area_json` array items that are already selected by means of [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method

```js
var area_json = [
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 1",
       "Locality": "Thistle Court,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 1147
    },
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 6",
       "Locality": "Great Western Road,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 4596
    },
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 7",
       "Locality": "Holburn Street,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 4380
    }
];

const res = area_json.filter(item => ![...$('.selected')].map(p => $(p).text()).includes(item.Sector));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="postcodes">
        <p class="selected">AB10 1</p>
        <p class="selected">AB10 6</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly thanks. But what are the three dots about just before $('.selected')? if I remove them it doesn't work properly

Comment: That's a [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to turn iterable jQuery object into array, so you can apply `.map()` method

Comment: You may do `Array.from($('.selected'))` instead, if you don't like that tripple dot thing for some reason

Comment: ...or, even `$('.selected').toArray()` ...somebody, stop me, please

Comment: And just one more little thing, if the number of selected `<p>` is large enough and you're willing to sacrifice conciseness for performance, you may assign `[...$('.selected')].map(p => $(p).text())` to the variable outside of `.filter()` not to do extra looping

Answer (score 2):

Try like this. in your `.each` loop try push the data and in filter you can check `.indexOf()`. this will give you the result.

> I moved `.filter` out of `.each` loop. because loop inside loop is a bad idea and it will consume time.

```js
var area_json = [
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 1",
       "Locality": "Thistle Court,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 1147
    },
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 6",
       "Locality": "Great Western Road,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 4596
    },
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 7",
       "Locality": "Holburn Street,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 4380
    }
];
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if( $('.postcodes p.selected').length ){
      var data = [];
        $('.postcodes p.selected').each(function(){
            data.push($(this).text());
        });
       var data_filter = area_json.filter((element) => {
        return (data.indexOf(element.Sector)<0)
       });
    }

    console.log(data_filter); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="postcodes">
        <p class="selected">AB10 1</p>
        <p class="selected">AB10 6</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use `each(function(index, item)` and `$(item).text()` , move console inside each.

```
 if( $('.postcodes p.selected').length ){
        $('.postcodes p.selected').each(function(index, item){
            var data_filter = area_json.filter((element) => {
                return element.Sector !== $(item).text();
            });
             console.log(data_filter); 
        });
    }
```

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data_filter = [];
    if( $('.postcodes p.selected').length ){
        $('.postcodes p.selected').each(function(index, item){
            data_filter = area_json.filter((element) => {
                return element.Sector !== $(item).text();
            });
            
        });
    }

    console.log(data_filter); 
}); 

var area_json = [
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 1",
       "Locality": "Thistle Court,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 1147
    },
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 6",
       "Locality": "Great Western Road,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 4596
    },
    {
       "Sector": "AB10 7",
       "Locality": "Holburn Street,Aberdeen",
       "Residential": 4380
    }
]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="postcodes">
        <p class="selected">AB10 1</p>
        <p class="selected">AB10 6</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to return a single JSON array so I can filter it again without any of the selected values inside it

Comment: I update answer, create a variable outside of each scope

Answer (score 1):

here is a working version I threw together:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var data_filter = [];
  var data_filterChecked = [];

  $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    data_filterChecked = [];

    if ($('.postcodes p.selected').length) {
      $('.postcodes p.selected').each(function(i, element) {
        var lookingFor = $(element).text();
        data_filter = area_json.filter((element) => {
          if (element.Sector !== lookingFor) {
            data_filterChecked.push(element);
          }

        });

      });
      data_filter = data_filterChecked;
    }

    console.log(data_filter);
  });

  var area_json = [{
      "Sector": "AB10 1",
      "Locality": "Thistle Court,Aberdeen",
      "Residential": 1147
    },
    {
      "Sector": "AC10 6",
      "Locality": "Great Western Road,Aberdeen",
      "Residential": 4596
    },
    {
      "Sector": "AB10 7",
      "Locality": "Holburn Street,Aberdeen",
      "Residential": 4380
    }
  ]

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
  <div class="postcodes">
    <p class="selected">AB10 1</p>
    <p class="selected">AB10 1</p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```